# Override jquery ui tooltipClass

Tags: css, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I'm trying to override the jquery ui tooltip class so i can apply a custom class. Using knockout to bind to a span in a cell in a row in a table. But the tooltipClass is ignored. Any idea why? Jquery-ui-1.10

```
    <div data-bind="visible:atleastOne">
        <table class="mytable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="1" class="white-back" />

                    <th class="border-bottom" colspan="5">Orders</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="title-column border-right" />
                    <th class="value-column">Account</th>
                    <th class="value-column">Amount</th>
                    <th class="value-column">Day</th>
                    <th class="value-column">Percentage</th>
                    <th class="value-column">Date</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: items, as: 'item' }">
                <!-- ko if: $parent.hasMultiple -->
                <tr>
                    <tdborder-right" colspan="5">
                        <span class="bold" data-bind="text: 'Item ' + item.Code()"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko foreach: { data: item.childen, as: 'child' } -->
                <tr style="display: none;">
                    <td data-bind="attr:{ id: 'tooltip-content-' + item.code() + '-' + child.code() }">
                        <div data-bind="template: 'data-template', data: $data">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- ko foreach: { data: child.readOnly.subOrders, as: 'sub' } -->

                <tr class="child-row" data-bind="css: { alt: $parentContext.$index() % 2 }">
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="visible: $index() == 0, text: item.readOnly.title, tooltip: {tooltipClass: 'test', show: true, content: '#tooltip-content-' + item.code() + '-' + child.code() }"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="text: sub.readOnly.acc"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="numeric">
                        <span data-bind="text: sub.readOnly.amount"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="text: sub.readOnly.day"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="numeric">
                        <span data-bind="text: sub.readOnly.percentage"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="text: sub.readOnly.date"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

css

```
 .test 
  {
     background:pink;
  }
```

If I add this to my stylesheet, the style is overridden wherever a tooltip is used as expected.

```
.ui-tooltip
 {
     background:blue;
 }
```

However, I need to specify a different style on different tooltips, so this won't work for me.

I tried targeting the table itself but it doesn't work:

```
.mytable .ui-tooltip 
{
   background:pink;
}
```

Comment: can you share the full table html?

Comment: Probably, you're adding the class before the tooltip initialization, meaning it gets overridden when the tooltip initializes.

Comment: @monotheist added in the full html

Comment: @RaduAndrei Great, how would i fix that?

Comment: Please inspect the element (span) using firebug and paste the generated innerHTML here.

Comment: @newbie_86 First, check the inspector to see if my assumption was correct - IF it was, I don't know how you would fix this. Depends on what parts of the markup the initialization changes. I would try to add a different property (maybe data-something) or different class (but all classes might be rewritten) ,wrap the whole thing in something, check to see if there's a callback on the tooltip etc. I'll take a look if you make a fiddle.

Comment: I would have thought a myTable.ui-tooltip would have worked - since overriding ui-tooltip works

Comment: @newbie_86 you want a custom tooltip style per table or per cell/span?

Comment: @monotheist Per table would work

Comment: Make sure you include the file that contains .mytable .ui-tooltip 
{
   background:pink;
}
 at the last.

Comment: that shouldn't be the issue, because the override style for ui-tooltip is in the same file and that kicks in